# Passing a weak fragment reference to a listadaptor, is this good practice?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, weak-references

I want to know if this is good practice and when using weak references is a good idea/bad idea...

When creating an adaptor I pass it (so it can call back to the fragment using an interface called "EmailOrdersButton") a weak reference to the fragment:

```
WeakReference<OrderHistoryListFragment> weakFragment = new WeakReference<OrderHistoryListFragment>(OrderHistoryListFragment.this);

adapter = new OrderHistoryListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.order_history_list_item, -1, orderHistory, isInEditMode, weakFragment);
```

Then in my adaptor constructor I have this:

```
public OrderHistoryListAdapter(Context mContext, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<MOHistory> lastTransactionList, boolean isEditModeEnable, WeakReference weakFragment) {
    mInflator = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.resource = resource;
    this.context = mContext;
    this.lastTransactionList = lastTransactionList;
    originalList = this.lastTransactionList;
    this.isEditModeEnable = isEditModeEnable;

    try {
        this.emailButtonCallback = ((EmailOrdersButton) weakFragment.get());
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Fragment must implement EmailOrdersButton.");
    }
}
```

Is this good practice to pass weak references of a fragment to an adaptor? I want to make sure my app is as memory efficient as possible

Answer (score 0):

A weak reference is used so that the fragment  are loosely coupled. If you don’t use a weak reference, it will not be garbage collected because the fragment maintains a reference to it.

As long as the lifetime of the fragment is within the lifetime of the Activity, then there's no need to use a WeakReference. If the fragment can live longer than the Activity, then you should use a WeakReference to avoid retaining the Activity in your object graph when the system destroys it.

Comment: And I guess the fragment in this case will always exist as long as the listadaptor will, which has a reference to the fragment. So therefore there is no need to create a weakreference?

Comment: Yes, in this particular scenario it is not needed. Its only needed when you need to implement loosely coupled architecture with system garbage to be executed.